# Retrieve a setCookie and processing a jQuery.Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am have trouble retrieve a `setCookie` and running a `jQuery.Post` with the data that is retrieved. Is marked in code  `//Post Issue`. The post method for `$urlcookie` is not firing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
          
          checkCookie()
          });
            
          function saveForm(){
          $current_url  = window.location
          $code_em = document.getElementById("cmsEM").value
          
          $url = "/validtrackcms_2302.php?cronsafe=mRT0SmaUDzDv2tgKfJhOzowifnyPc4&current_url="+$current_url+"&code_em="+$code_em+"&name=null&phone=null&company=null";
          $urlcookie = "/validtrackcms_2302.php?cronsafe=mRT0SmaUDzDv2tgKfJhOzowifnyPc4&current_url="+$current_url+"&code_em="+$getCode_em+"&name=null&phone=null&company=null";

          jQuery.post( $url, function( data ) {
            console.log(data)
            if(data != 1){
            //show the error message
            alert("OOPS!")
            }else{
            setCookie("cmsuser",new Date().getTime(), 1)
            setCookie("pevent", "live",1)
            setCookie("page_url_live","2302",1)
            setCookie("code_em",$code_em,1)
            window.location.reload()
            {"}"}
            {"}"});
            
            }
            
            
            //cookie section
            function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
              var d = new Date();
              d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 1000));
              var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
              document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
            }
            
            function getCookie(cname) {
              var name = cname + "=";
              var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
              for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                  c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                  return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
              }
              return "";
            }
            
            function checkCookie() {
              var cmsuser = getCookie("cmsuser");
              var pevent = getCookie("pevent");
              var page_url_live = getCookie("page_url_live");
              var getCode_em = getCookie("code_em");
              if(pevent != "live" ){
              jQuery('#modalWin').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
            }else{
              jQuery('#modalWin').remove();
 //Post Issue
              jQuery.post( $urlcookie, function( data_urlc );
              console.log(data_urlc);
            }
            }
  
// ]]></script>
```